# Laravel 3 - error: Connection to smtp.gmail.com:465 Timed Out

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, timeout

I want to send email through laravel-3, but i am facing one error like this:

```
ERROR: Connection to smtp.gmail.com:465 Timed Out
```

I am using Swiftmailer Messages-master bundle to send emails, and I have written this code in my controller:

```
Config::set('messages::config.transports.smtp.host', 'smtp.gmail.com');
Config::set('messages::config.transports.smtp.port', 465);
Config::set('messages::config.transports.smtp.username','abc@gmail.com');
Config::set('messages::config.transports.smtp.password', 'mypassword');
Config::set('messages::config.transports.smtp.encryption', 'ssl');

Message::send(function($message)
{
    $message->to('xyz@gmail.com');
    $message->from('abc@gmail.com', 'Kishan Vadaliya');

    $message->subject('Email checking');
    $message->body('hii i am very happy for send this email through laravel');
});
```

Please help me to solve my error...

Answer (score 0):

only remove semicolon in php.ini file from your php folder of wamp server

instead of this line in php.ini
   ;extension=php_openssl.dll
you have to write (only remove semicolon)
    extension=php_openssl.dll

after that you have to restart your wamp
Now, its work properly..

Thanks.